# How to fix the "Nullpointer Exception", when trying to get a IGuildUser from a IGuild

Tags: c#, discord.net

I don't know what I'm fundamentally doing wrong.

I'm trying to check if a user is on a certain Server (via UserID and ServerID) and later check his permissions.

After using `DiscordSocketClient.GetGuild(serverid)` I get a IGuild (Its not null and I can see its ID). But when I try to get the Users via `IGuild.Users` I get a empty list (`IGuild.GetUserAsync()` returns an empty GuildUser).

Do I have to do something to load them first?

```cs
    public IGuildUser GetUserFromServer(ulong userid, ulong serverid) {
        IGuildUser gu = null;
        try {
            IGuild g = _client.GetGuild(serverid);
            Console.WriteLine("GuildID: "+g.Id);
            gu=g.GetUserAsync(userid).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("UserID: "+gu.Id);
            } catch(Exception e) { 
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
            }
        return gu;
    }
```

Edit 1: gu is null and `Task<IGuildUser>.Status` returns `RanToCompletion`

Comment: Could it be something like there being no user with that `userid`? Or that they are in a different guild?

Comment: Just call g.GetUserAsync(userid) first without .Result and check what you got.

Comment: `Task<IGuildUser>.Status` returns `RanToCompletion`

Comment: Can't you simply do:- `public IGuildUser GetUserFromServer(ulong userid, ulong serverid)
{
    return _client.GetGuild(serverid)?.GetUser(userid);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have can be written as follows

```cs
public IGuildUser GetUserFromServer(ulong userid, ulong serverid) 
{ 
    return _client.GetGuild(serverid)?.GetUser(userid); 
}
```

If a guild could not be found for the given id, return null, else attempt to retrieve the user. The method would either return null (if no user is found) or the user as an IGuildUser.
There is a chance that the user may actually be in the guild, but they aren't present in cache, in that case, you can fallback to a rest request.

```cs
public async Task<IGuildUser> GetUserFromServer(ulong userid, ulong serverid)
{
    return _client.GetGuild(serverid)?.GetUser(userid) ?? await _client.Rest.GetGuildUserAsync(serverid, userid);
}
```

With this option, if you cannot retrieve the user from cache, execute a rest request to confirm that the use truly is not a member of the guild. You can do this by accessing the `DiscordSocketRestClient` which is exposed as a property on the `DiscordSocketClient`